# Android how to create file in Phone memory

Tags: android

How do i create a file in phone memory instead of SD card.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should only have access to the directories possessing the correct access rights for your application.

Usually, you will use the method `Context.getDir("example", MODE_PRIVATE)` to get a writeable directory on the phone memory.

It creates a directory called `/data/data/[package_name]/app_example`.

You will then be able to create files in that directory.

You can also use :

```
FileOutputStream f = context.openFileOutput("filetest", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

which will create and open a file named `/data/data/[package name]/files/filetest`.