# Using phone memory instead of SDCARD

Tags: android, audio-recording

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android how to create file in Phone memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288367/android-how-to-create-file-in-phone-memory)

I am recording my voice in android using MediaRecorder,But am using SDCARD to store this recorded voice.I want to use phone memory instead of SDCARD.
recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard//a.wav); how can i use phone memory here instead of sdcard where "recorder" is a MediaRecorder object.

Comment: Refer to these,

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288367/android-how-to-create-file-in-phone-memory][1]

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316629/how-to-read-file-from-the-phone-memory-in-android][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288367/android-how-to-create-file-in-phone-memory
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316629/how-to-read-file-from-the-phone-memory-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Try using the methods in the `Context` class

```
Context.getFilesDir()
Context.openFileOutput( name, mode )
```