# How to save file in the memory of phone?

Tags: java, android

I have been developing an application which needs to download a file from the Internet and save it into memory; application doesn't need to save directly on to the SD card, because the SD card may be full. How can I save the file in memory using Java? Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288367/android-how-to-create-file-in-phone-memory

Comment: user1166635: use temporary file to save data in  phone memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need the data, why not just save the data in memory?
If you really need to save to a file, maybe below is what you need:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MemoryFile.html

Comment: I want to save file into the SD Card, and I'm going to do following actions: 1) Download file into the memory 2) Check size of it and a free space on the SDCard 3) If it has free space, the application will save file into the sdcard

Comment: Well in this case, I think it's better to: Either check the size first so that you can reserve the space on SDcard, or download and save the data to SDcard, and when any write() fails because of insufficient space, cancel the download.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I think you can use the `GetDir` function of `Intent` class.

Take a look at the next link.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

I hope this helps.